# How to get the id of views in other apps?

Tags: android

I need the id of views in a dialer app to use them with accessibility service

Comment: There are dozens, if not hundreds, of "dialer apps", across the thousands of Android device models. The widgets on those dialer apps' screens will vary widely. You might also wish to consider whether your app will meet [Google's current guidelines regarding accessibility services](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/google-cracks-down-on-power-user-apps-that-use-androids-accessibility-api/), if you were planning on distributing your app via the Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with the [Android device monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html)
Or ADM for short, we just need to make sure to run the app whether on the emulator or on the physical device and then select it from the left hand pane and then click on the "take screenshot" option on top of such pane. After taking the screenshot all the properties of the views contained on the ui can be found on the properties pane shown on the right hand side,you just need to make sure to select the desired view with the cursor.

There's a newer tool called Layout inspector. I couldn't make it to work with my device though, just with the emulator that's why I don't add it as the proper answer..